# Gain count of new posts in VBulletin

Tags: php, mysql, vbulletin

I'm new to `vbulletin/php`.
I need to define a number of new posts (exactly count of threads where the user sees the page http://www.exampleVBForum.com/search.php?do=getnew, are shown). And it's very important that no changes will be made.

This code will execute every 10 minutes, and I don't want that all threads set mark as read for users (or something like that).
I use this code:

```
$datecut= TIMENOW - ($vbulletin->options['markinglimit'] * 86400);

$newCount = $db->query_read_slave("
            SELECT count(*) as totCount
            FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "thread
            Where
            thread.lastpost >= $datecut
            AND thread.visible IN (0,1,2)
            AND thread.sticky IN (0,1)
            AND thread.open <> 10");
```

Does it exactly return the number of new posts that will be shown in http://www.exampleVBForum.com/search.php?do=getnew page?

Comment: `does it exactly returns number of new posts that will shown in http://www.exampleVBForum.com/search.php?do=getnew page?` - I don't know, does it? It's your code on your server, you tell us what it does...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend reviewing the code in this mod as it does exactly what you are looking to do.

http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=231060&highlight=unread+posts